# My App downloads twice when uploaded to app store

Tags: iphone, ios

When my app got accepted to the App Store, it would download the newest version 4.1, immediately after the download is complete, it shows an update is ready, but it shows the update to be 4.1 as well, This is not Apple's fault as I have read before, I assume it is my fault. Why? Well, because this isnt the first time it has happened to me, I uploaded this same app version 3.9 and it did the same thing, but I never found out how to fix it, so i worked on an update for some minor bugs and hoped that when I re-uploaded it, it would get fixed. Does anybody know of a reason for this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be downloading it too quickly. I have experienced that the meta data will update before your app in the store so if you download it right away you may be getting a previous version. After a little time passes it will update the download and then give you a notification that there is an update and download the recent version.

Comment: Right, I read something like this elsewhere, but it doesn't download the previous version, it originally downloads 4.1, then shows and update for 4.1 which is what i dont understand!

Comment: are you downloading it once you get the itunesconnect email or when you get the notification from the app store? If you wait till it lets you know its ready then it may not have that problem.

Comment: Yes, i waited until it let me know via itunesconnect. It said `ready for sale` so i went into the app store, and it said `4.1` with the new update features that i put. And after its done downloading, it says there is an update for `4.1`, which is `4.1` so its just downloading an update, which is really just the version thats already on the phone

Comment: I think that's your problem and how I've seen it. If you were to delete your app now and reinstall it from the app store it probably won't double download. itunesconnect will let you know about it too quickly.

Comment: You know what, it says the newest version is 4.1 but it downloads the previous 3.9 version!

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I've seen as well.

Comment: Really! That is interesting. It has happened to me the past 2 or 3 updates. And it doesnt't fix ever. Even after waiting, What have you seen as an option to fix it? Or shall i contact dev support? Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: I don't know if there is anything to do but there is a good chance that there is no real problem for the users. You can contact dev support to see what they say but the real test is on another device long after you get the email from itunesconnect.